# css positioning - Horizontal align

Tags: css, alignment, positioning

I'm working on making a simple photography website for someone, and I'm stuck trying to figure out the horizontal positioning. I have the margins set to auto on left/right, and the position set on relative. It should go in the middle, shouldn't it?

I have a picture slideshow that I want in the middle, and then there's the navigation that I have on the right side. The nav is in the right place, but the slideshow is stuck overlapping with the navigation and I can't figure out how to get it to center horizontally.

Here's the nav:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 22%;
    right: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The rogue slider:

```
#slider {
    background:#000;
    border:5px solid #eaeaea;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
```

The slider is contained in the wrapper div:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 55%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #eaeaea;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

What can be done to get this right?

If you need more info, you can take a look at the page and source code:
[bwphotog.com](http://bwphotog.webege.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child `.container` element is wider than its parent, `.wrapper`. If you remove the `960px` width of the container it will be centralized.

Comment: Ah... I should not have missed that. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Change your .container class to this

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* width: 960px; */
}
```